# rcviz NameError: name 'node_data' not defined

Tags: python, recursion, module, pygraphviz

I'm trying to use the [rcviz](https://github.com/carlsborg/rcviz) module.

I followed the instructions in the Readme (for python 3) without errors.

```
python -m venv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate
python setup.py install
```

But when

```
python example_qsort.py
```

I get the error
`NameError: name 'node_data' not defined`

The full error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/andre/essais/python/rcviz/example_qsort.py", line 2, in <module>
    from rcviz import callgraph, viz
  File "/home/andre/essais/python/rcviz/rcviz/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .rcviz import callgraph, viz
  File "/home/andre/essais/python/rcviz/rcviz/rcviz.py", line 12, in <module>
    class callgraph(object):
  File "/home/andre/essais/python/rcviz/rcviz/rcviz.py", line 17, in callgraph
    _callers: Dict[int, node_data] = {}  # caller_fn_id : node_data
NameError: name 'node_data' is not defined
```

Comment: I see in the source that the `node_data` class is defined after the `callgraph` class. Maybe that's why...

Answer (score 0):

Self-resolved.

- Cloned [rcviz fork](https://github.com/DamnedFacts/rcviz).
- `cd rcviz`
- `python setup.py install --user`
- `python example_qsort.py`

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed in the original repo.